# Is there a tool for getting a IP's domain?

Tags: open-source

We know the domain can resolve to a IP address. 
and we can use the `nslookup` tool to get a domain's IP address.

Is there a tool for get the domain of a IP?
when I provide a IP, then I can get the domain.

Comment: You might have difficulty finding a tool that will reliably report a domain name against an IP address. Virtual hosts can share IP addresses and there's no way for a local tool to determine the hostnames used on those IP addresses.There are a _lot_ of virtual hosts out there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nslookup` and `whois` for this as well.

The `nslookup` on an IP will return RDNS info (reverse DNS).  This if often used for spam fighting, etc.  Note that the owner of the IP or subnet the IP is in will need to configure this.

The `whois` on an IP will return back the information as to the person/group that "owns" the subnet.  Note that on a large subnet (say, `64.0.0.0/8`) it will be broken up into smaller and smaller subnets, so while Sprint or AT&T or whoever owns the entire `/8` subnet, "ownership" of extremely small pieces may be transferred to other entities.